# Varying Enum Arguments

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to create an enum with parameters that differ in type. For example:

```
enum test {
    foo(true, 5), //true is a boolean, 5 is an integer
    bar(20, 50), //both arguments are integers 
//........
}
```

When I write the enum constructor it can only fit the description of one of the two variables. It could either be:

```
enum test {
    foo(true, 5), //true is a boolean, 5 is an integer
    bar(20, 50); //both arguments are integers 

    private boolean bool;
    private int i;

    private test(boolean bool, int i) {
    this.bool = bool;
    this.i = i;
    }
}
```

Or the constructor can be:

```
private test(int i, int i1) {
    this.i = i;
    this.i1 = i1;
    }
```

Is there any way I can have multiple enum variables each with different parameters(different type)

Comment: just make it 3 parameters (`bool, i, i1`) and set the one you don't need to `0` or `false`. There is no way that items of type `test` have a different set of variables.

Comment: overload the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can *overload* constructors, that is,
have multiple constructors with the same name but with different signature.
As usual when using overloading, make sure to use it judiciously, as explained in [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=4).

```
  enum MyEnum {
    foo(true, 5),
    bar(20, 50);

    private boolean bool;
    private int num1;
    private int num2;

    MyEnum(boolean bool, int num) {
      this.bool = bool;
      this.num1 = num;
    }

    MyEnum(int num1, int num2) {
      this.num1 = num1;
      this.num2 = num2;
    }
  }
```